# How to order and mark duplicated rows at the same time

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, duplicates

I am looking to make a new variable to mark which of my data is duplicated, selecting the oldest datapoint to be the "original". My dataframe is ordered by date, but by ID.

```
ID      Name        Number         Datetime (dd/mm/yyy/hh/MM)
1       ace         114            15.03.2019 15:26
2       bert        197            18.03.2019 07:28
3       vance       245            16.03.2019 14:03
4       chad        116            17.03.2019 02:02
5       chad        116            18.03.2019 18:23
6       ace         114            12.03.2019 23:15
```

Ordering the dataframe works and selecting the duplicated lines also works, but not in combination, which leads to the originals not being the first presentation. Even if I order the dataframe before marking the represenation the dataframe is seems to be unordered for the next command and linking the two commands with %>% is not working.

```
df %>% arrange(Datetime) 
df$representations <- if_else(duplicated(df$number, .keep_all =TRUE), 1, 0)

df$represntations <- df %>%
   arrange(Datetime) %>%
   if_else(duplicated(df$number, .keep_all =TRUE), 1, 0)
```

How can i be sure, that the the originals will be the first datapoint to the number (like this)?

```
ID      Name        Number         Datetime (dd/mm/yyy/hh/MM)  representation
1       ace         114            15.03.2019 15:26            1
2       bert        197            18.03.2019 07:28            0
3       vance       245            16.03.2019 14:03            0
4       chad        116            17.03.2019 02:02            0
5       chad        116            18.03.2019 18:23            1
6       ace         114            12.03.2019 23:15            0
```

Comment: In your question you said "selecting the oldest datapoint", but in your desired output, the rows marked with representation = 1 is the newest timepoints of `Name`

Comment: @benson23, yes I was not clear on that. The representation = 1 are the ones that will be excluded

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
df <- df %>%
   arrange(Datetime) %>%
   mutate(representations = if_else(duplicated(number, .keep_all =TRUE), 1, 0))  %>% 
   arrange(ID)
```

Comment: thanks! I tried this, but it seems the arrange does not accept this format of date, as the order is now 1.4.2019 - 1.5.2019 - 2.4.2019 - 2.5.2019 and so on

Comment: This means your date column is actually a character column. Convert to date first and then try.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  arrange(`Datetime(dd/mm/yyy/hh/MM)`) %>% 
  mutate(flag = duplicated(Number)*1) %>% 
  arrange(ID)
```

```
  1 ace      114 15.03.2019                      1
2     2 bert     197 18.03.2019                      0
3     3 vance    245 16.03.2019                      0
4     4 chad     116 17.03.2019                      0
5     5 chad     116 18.03.2019                      1
6     6 ace      114 12.03.2019                      0
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this code and the sample I checked seemed to be correct, thank you! (even though the as.Date changed the year from 2019 to 2020, but the order is correct)

```
# split time and date, so as.Date can be used 
emerge$date <- as.Date(sapply(strsplit(as.character(emerge$Falleinzeitdatum.Notfall), " "), "[", 1), format = "%d.%m.%y")

# arrange as proposed
emerge <- emerge %>% 
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(re = if_else(duplicated(Patientennummer, .keep_all = TRUE), 1, 0))
```